# How to get a pyTorch TabNet unsupervised model to impute missing data using TabNetPretrainer

Tags: python, imputation, unsupervised-learning

I am trying to impute data before building a model. There are a few features that occasionally are `nan` and I need to impute them before running `TabNetClassifier` from `pytorch_tabnet`.
My understanding was that you could use the `TabNetPretrainer` to create an unsupervised model to do so:

```
unsupervised_model = TabNetPretrainer(
    optimizer_fn=optim.Adam,
    optimizer_params=dict(lr=2e-2),
    mask_type='entmax', # "sparsemax"
    )

unsupervised_model.fit(
    X_train=X_train,
    eval_set=X_val,
    pretraining_ratio=0.8,
)
```

However if I run the code above I get an error because `X_train` and `X_val` have some `nan`:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

If I train with the `nan` records removed:

```
unsupervised_model.fit(
    X_train=X_train_noNan,
    eval_set=X_val_noNan,
    pretraining_ratio=0.8,
)
```

The model builds, but when I run `predict` on a cut of the dataset that has some `nan` for the features, it errors out like so:

```
RuntimeError: index -1 is out of bounds for dimension 1 with size 20
```

How can I go about imputing my data with the unsupervised model or have I misunderstood something? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I either drop NAs or use a fill method to change NA to 0 or the previous value. This is done before splitting the data.

```
    df = dropna(df)
```

fill with zeros

```
    df = df.fillna(0)
```

forward fill

```
    df = df.fillna(method="ffill")
```

That error may not have anything to do with the na problem. That error is usually what I get if my dataset is being split somewhere, resulting in only some of the columns making it to the predict fuction.